# Bootstrap image in CSS background image

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using bootstrap with my rails 4 app.

I have a profile page with each profile having a hero image.

My profile model has a 'hero' attribute, which is the string to the image itself.

I'm wondering whether I can define the css for the hero image placement as:

```
<%= @profile.hero %>
```

That would mean my CSS for the div container has:

```
background-image: image-url('<%= @profile.hero %> ');
```

Would that be the best way to manage that? Alternatively, how would I go about setting the CSS, size etc for the image properties to then have a div tag for that CSS, which just includes  <%= @profile.hero %> inside that div?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't use controller or view variables inside of CSS files (they a static i.e. precompilled outside of you query execution scope).

So, one way to solve your problem is using something like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<%= @profile.hero %>');">
</div>
```